# AWS / S3 / Static site: How to filter sourcemap or .map files from being served

Tags: amazon-s3

We are deploying a React app (created using create-react-app) into AWS S3 and serve it as a static site.

The build contains lot of sourcemap files with the extension of .map.

We know that, with the following line in package.json, we can disable the sourcemap file generation

`"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",`

But we don't want to do that.  We want to have the .map files but it should not be served by S3.

Please provide your suggestions to turn on or off any settings in S3 so that the sourcemap files are not served.

Thanks